# R Script on cluster of machines using parallel library

Tags: r, ssh, parallel-processing, rstudio, remote-access

I have two windows machines, both have R installed. I am trying to use one as a master and salve in order to speed up processing of my data. I would have a total of 12 cores to to run the script across,I am using ssh to achieve this.

1. FreeSSHD has been installed on both machines
2. Putty has been installed on both machines
3. I can remote SSH to both machines perfectly fine ,no issues.

I am using the sample code below to  to run my script in a master and slave fashion, as outlined by:
http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/running-r-jobs-quickly-on-many-machines/

```
    primary <- '171.27.27.190'
    machineAddresses <- list(list(host=primary,user='james',ncore=2),list(host='173.29.50.45',user='james',ncore=4))

    spec <- lapply(machineAddresses,(function(machine) {rep(list(list(host=machine$host,user=machine$user)), machine$ncore)}))
    spec <- unlist(spec,recursive=FALSE)

    parallelCluster <- parallel::makeCluster(type='PSOCK',master=primary,spec=spec)
    print(parallelCluster)
```

The script just hangs in R and seems to be waiting for an input adn i have to click warning is printed below.

```
running command 'ssh -l james 171.27.27.190 "\"C:/Users/james/DOCUME~1/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/Rscript\" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e \"parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()\" MASTER=171.27.27.190 PORT=11923 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE"' had status 127
```

I have tried different variation of the connections above, it it porduces a similar error. is it a bug in the libary ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that it tries to run `ssh`.  The exit code, which is `127`, tells us that the `ssh` command was not found.  You can verify this in R, by calling:

```
> Sys.which("ssh")
ssh
""
```

which means that `ssh` is not on the search `PATH`.  Now, you most likely don't have an `ssh` command on your Windows system.  Instead, since you mentioned PuTTY, you should have the `plink` command.  On my Windows 8.1 where I installed PuTTY using the default settings, I get:

```
> Sys.which("plink")
                           plink 
"C:\\PROGRA~1\\PuTTY\\plink.exe"
```

If you still get `""`, you need to update your `PATH` to contain `C:\PROGRA~1\PuTTY` (or wherever you've installed PuTTY).

With the above in place, install the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author):

```
install.packages("future")
```

The reason for using the future package, instead of parallel, is that it (i) provides verbose output, but more importantly, it (ii) uses reverse SSH tunneling avoiding hassles with firewalls etc when the remote machine tries to connect back to your local machine (which it needs to do).

See if the following works:

```
> library("future")
> cl <- makeClusterPSOCK("171.27.27.190", user = "james", 
          rshcmd = c("plink", "-ssh", "-i", "C:/Users/james/.ssh/putty.ppk"),
          homogeneous = FALSE, verbose = TRUE)
Starting worker #1 on ‘171.27.27.190’: "plink" "-ssh" "-i" "C:/Users/james/.ssh/putty.ppk" -R 11671:localhost:11671 -l james 171.27.27.190 "\"Rscript\" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e \"parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()\" MASTER=localhost PORT=11671 OUT= TIMEOUT=2592000 XDR=TRUE"
Waiting for worker #1 on ‘171.27.27.190’ to connect back
Connection with worker #1 on ‘171.27.27.190’ established
```

You'll see different port numbers than 11671, but otherwise it should look the same.

Note, you do need to have SSH key authentication set up between your local machine and your remote machine. That is what the `"-i", "C:/Users/james/.ssh/putty.ppk"` options are about; it tells `plink -ssh` to use your *private* SSH key to connect to the remote machine. The remote machine must have your *public* SSH key listed.  There is no way around this - you do need to be able to SSH into the remote machine without entering a password (and this is also how the parallel package works).  You can generate your public-private SSH key pair using `PuTTYgen`.  So, if you don't have this already setup, make sure you can do it using PuTTY by itself.  Only when that works, try to access it from R.